# Give the set of points of continuity of $f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ in real domain

Tags: calculus, continuity

For all $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ I found that $f$ is not continuous. The problem is to prove that $f$ is continuous for $p \not \in \mathbb{Z}$. I got stuck in my attempt in the following, first pinning the integer domain:

- $\forall \ p \not \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \ x \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \epsilon > 0, \ f(p) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(p) + \epsilon \Leftrightarrow p - \lfloor p \rfloor - \epsilon < x - \lfloor x \rfloor < p - \lfloor p \rfloor +\epsilon$
- $\Leftrightarrow \lfloor x \rfloor + p - \lfloor p \rfloor - \epsilon<x< \lfloor x \rfloor + p - \lfloor p \rfloor + \epsilon$

From here I could not continue, neither found an open interval $I$ such that $p \in I \Rightarrow f(p)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(p)+\epsilon.$ Or a $\delta>0$ from the classical definition. Any suggestions or different approaches?

Comment: It should be noted that the discontinuities of $\phi(x, \lfloor x \rfloor)$ for continuous $\phi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ (for example $\phi=-$) are $\mathbb Z$. So, your answer should not rely on the fact that there is a subtraction - simply compute the discontinuities of $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ and compose with your continuous operator to get your answer. So the answer is $\mathbb Z$ is the set of discontinuities of your compositional image under $\phi$.

Comment: Have you had the idea to draw the graphical representation of $f$ ?

Comment: @Jean Marie being honestly I didn't think in doing this before, but it really clarifies how the continuity is true for all non integer points and also the discontinuities in the integer ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $p\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, then both $\lfloor p\rfloor$ and $\lfloor p\rfloor+1$ are not equal to $p$, so $p\in (\lfloor p\rfloor,\lfloor p\rfloor+1)$, and we take $\delta'>0$ such that $(p-\delta',p+\delta')\subset (\lfloor p\rfloor,\lfloor p\rfloor+1)$. Now let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to find $\delta$ such that if $x\in (p-\delta,p+\delta)$ then $|f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon$. Note that if $x\in(\lfloor p\rfloor,\lfloor p\rfloor+1)$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor p\rfloor$. Therefore we need to take $\delta<\delta'$. Then if $|x-p|<\delta$, we see that: $$|f(x)-f(p)|=|x-\lfloor x\rfloor-p-\lfloor p\rfloor|=|x-p|<\delta$$ So in order for this expression to be less than $\varepsilon$, we also need $\delta\leq\varepsilon$. This gives us that $\delta=\min\{\delta',\varepsilon\}$ does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ and $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\leqslant\varepsilon$ and that $\delta$ is smaller than both $p-\lfloor p\rfloor$ and $\lfloor p\rfloor+1-p$. Then, if $x-p<\delta$, you have $x\in\bigl(\lfloor p\rfloor,\lfloor p\rfloor+1\bigr)$, and therefore $x-\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\lfloor p\rfloor$. So$$\bigl|\bigl(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\bigr)-\bigl(p-\lfloor p\rfloor\bigr)\bigr|=|x-p|<\delta\leqslant\varepsilon.$$

Comment: How did you find the lower bound $\lfloor p \rfloor$ of $x \in (\lfloor p \rfloor, \lfloor p \rfloor + 1)$ given the previous hypotheses? I couldn't figured it out, sorry.

Comment: Let $n=\lfloor p\rfloor$. If $|x-p|<\delta$, then, in particular, $x$ is closer to $p$ than both $n$ and $n+1$, by the choice of $\delta$ (note that $\delta$ is smaller than the distances from $p$ to $n$ and to $n+1$). So,$$x\in(n,n+1)=\bigl(\lfloor p\rfloor,\lfloor p\rfloor+1\bigr).$$

Comment: Ok, so you forgot the modulus in the previous answer ($|x-p|<\delta$), right? If so, then I get your point. Just one more little detail, it would not be incorrect to use $|x-p|\leq\varepsilon$ instead of $< \varepsilon$?

Comment: I mislead myself in the last part, $\leq \varepsilon $ also holds the continuity, sorry.